# Equivalent of calling ".auth/refresh" endpoint through jQuery for C#

Tags: c#, azure, refresh-token, easy-auth

Following [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens#refresh-auth-tokens), when we are using Azure Easy Auth, we can call ".auth/refresh" endpoint from jQuery in a very simple way:

```
$.ajax("/.auth/refresh").done(function() {
  console.log("Token refresh completed successfully.");
})
```

When we reload the page, the access token in the headers will contain an updated expiration date:

[image]

My question is, how can we do this from C#? I tried calling the refresh GET endpoint by using HttpClient and leaving the headers blank, this didn't work. Then I tried putting the refresh token in the header as bearer and turning it into a POST request like some sources online stated. This all yielded the same 401 responses.

Is there a simpler way of doing this? This seems anything but "Easy".

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I already configured Refresh Tokens on the App Service by following the guide further up in that link I provided. I get it in the headers.

Comment: Have you checked what cookies are being sent with the jQuery method, it could be that the token is being sent this way instead. I certainly don't see any extra headers being added

Comment: Yeah it's working when I add the `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie from `HttpContext.Request` to the headers of a `HttpRequestMessage` with `Cookie` as key and a semicolon-separated list of the cookie key-value pairs like so `cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2`. Oddly enough, I can't find anything about this when googling for the cookie name and the refresh endpoint.